# How to change default parsley.js UI/UX behaviour?

Tags: javascript, parsley.js

Here is documentation about UI/UX ([link](http://parsleyjs.org/doc/index.html#ui)). But default parsley.js mottos not suitable for my project, especially the following:

> 3. **Quick error removal**: when a field is detected and shown as invalid,
>      further checks are done on each keypress to try to quickly remove
>      error messages once the field is ok.

Now I've set `{uiEnabled: false}` and want manually to implement behaviour, which is suitable for me. Here is few thing I need:

- I don't want parsley to bind keypress event. Revalidation must be done only with next submit.
- Is it possible to show errors block for the particular form item? I mean after validation with disabled UI, I have all information about invalid objects, but I can't find public API method which will append error block for some item[s].
- `parsleyField.addError` not working with disabled UI

How can I implement this with parsley.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Change the `triggerAfterFailure` option to `''`.
- Look at the `errorsContainer` option. Could be a function that does the append I believe.

Good luck.

Comment: It works only with `{uiEnabled: true} `, otherwise `addError` will fail with error because `*._ui` in fact is `null`